# How to substitute the PointerEvent in Jest? (PointerEvent is not defined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

## Problem

In my react app I test for different event constructors in a switch case statement. Something like that:

```
switch (event.constructor) {
    case String:
        doSomething()
        break;
    case Array:
        doSomething()
        break;
    case Date:
        doSomething()
        break;
    case PointerEvent:
        doSomething()
        break;
    default:
        doSomething()
        break;
```

If I test this setup with jest it always throws me the error `ReferenceError: PointerEvent is not defined`. I can fix this problem by setting `PointerEvent` to `window.PointerEvent`. But the event in my jest environment has the type `MouseEvent`.

## Question

How can I set the PointerEvent as an alias for the MouseEvent during testing? Or is there even a way to import an execute a PointerEvent in jest?

## System

```
"@mui/material": "^5.6.3",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
"react": "^18.0.0",
"react-dom": "^18.0.0",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [this](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/245#issuecomment-576296325) issue, you can see that `jsdom` appears to not implement `PointerEvent`

You can work around this this though

```
class MockPointerEvent {}

describe("PointerEvent", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    global.window.PointerEvent = MockPointerEvent as any;
  });

  it("confirms pointer event", () => {
    const pointerEvent = new PointerEvent("");

    expect(pointerEvent).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```